# Virtualized Linux on my Windows 7, which is the IP of the linux?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, vmware-player

I have installed debian on my windows 7 with vmware player. I would like to access it with SSH from Windows 7.

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should install OpenSSH server on your Debian. Open up a command prompt in Debian and execute:

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install ssh
```

Next, reboot the virtual Debian machine and make sure you got a copy of an SSH client for windows. (e.g. [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html))

On the Debian machine, execute `ifconfig`, and check the IP that's behind `inet addr:`. Open up PuTTY and input the IP address, it should then open an SSH connection to your virtual Debian machine.

Comment: don't forget to open up the ssh port in iptables... sometimes this will be the culprit if you're unable to connect properly